# Import glsl file in angular nx project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, glsl, shader

I'm trying to import a glsl file (without requiring module with require()) in components but seems not working.

My first try was create a glsl.d.ts file with module declaration as follow:

```js
declare module '*.glsl' {
  const value: string
  export default value
}
```

This solve the warning, but a dedicated loader seems required.

My second try was to use custom-webpack and glslify-loader with the following configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert|png|svg|jpg|gif|obj)$/,
        use: [
            'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

But still not works...

Can someone help me?

[Here the stackbliz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nx-sample)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it couldn't resolve is that it cannot determine the type of the object , So its necessary that we have to mention the type of the object , So if we mention something like this would resolve our problem.

```
const material_surafce = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({vertexShader: shaderContends})
```

We can also use a file loader directly using `"THREE.FileLoader().load",` This might also help us in resolving the issue.

There is one more approach the shader file would be a string , So what we can do is that we can get the contends of the files through `socket.io` and send to the client to load it onLoad. I have never done this before.